# Как спарсить div без класса?

Tags: python, selenium, bs4

Есть html, в котором помимо тегов с классами хранятся дивы без классов.

Мне нужно спарсить один из таких. Когда пытаюсь использовать bs4 и find - выдается None.

Также, пыталась с помощью селениума найти элемент по xpath, но тогда он просто выдает код элемента:

```
xpath2 = '/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]'

element2 = browser.find_element("xpath", xpath)
```

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Чтоб получить текст элемента - element2.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прикрепите пример/часть html, будет немного проще вам помочь
Если использовать bs4, то вы можете сначала найти элемент в котором находятся нужные вам div'ы, а затем уже в этом элементе производить поиск find('div'). Либо find_all('div'), а затем уже в найденных отбирать те которые вам нужны.

Вероятнее всего какая-то проблема при использовании bs4, т.к. если div'ы присутствуют, а вам выдаёт None, значит что-то не так (Либо iframe который bs4 не видит, либо что-то еще). Если есть возможность, то любые подробности помогут вам подсказать в чем дело (Для начала кусок html)